# what is the actual meaning of $K^p$ in perfect field $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation

I have some  confusion regarding Dummit and foote Book Algebra, page number $549$

It is written that

> A field  $K$ of characteristics  $p$ is called  perfect  if every  element of $K$ is  a  $p^{th}$ power  in $K$ i,e $K= K^p$.

**My confusion** : what is the meaning of $K^p?$

**My thinking** : I have two thoughts about this.

$1.$If $K= \mathbb{F}_p$ then $$K^p=  \mathbb{F}_{p^p}$$

$\implies K^p$ denote the algebraic closure of $K$

$2.$If $K= \mathbb{F}_p$ then $$K^p= \left( \mathbb{F}_p \right)^p$$
$\implies  \underbrace{K\times ....\times K}_{\text{p times}}=   \underbrace{\mathbb{F}_p\times ....\times \mathbb{F}_p}_{\text{p times}}$

Here  im confused that what is the actual  meaning of $K^p?$

Comment: It means the $p-$powers of all the elements in $K$.

Comment: The definition forces the meaning of $K^p$.  It is the set of all $p$th powers.

Comment: Also, they define this notation earlier.

Comment: @ElliotG: It doesn't look like it's attempting to define "characteristic". It's defining "perfect".

Comment: @Troposphere you’re right; totally misread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $K^p$ *in itself* can have several imaginable meanings, but if "i.e." in your quote has its usual meaning (namely, that it connects different ways of expressing the same thought), the only meaning for $K^p$ that makes sense in context is
$$ K^p = \{ k^p \mid k \in K \} $$

This is an instance of the general practice of writing $f(X)$ for $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ when $X$ is known to be a set of things that the notation $f(\phantom{x})$ makes sense for.

---

Note, by the way, that $\mathbb F_{p^p}$ is *not* the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ -- an algebraic closure is always infinite.